# Homework: Array's for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Write a program to input a series of 12 integers from the keyboard and store them in a one-dimensional array, x[12], then displayed them on the computer screen in reverse order.

I have a basic understanding that:
My numbers in the array will go from {0 to 11}
I am using a for loop (which I don't currently know how to do)

Now... How do I write this program?

Comment: Have you looked at any of the tutorials if you search on "For loop C++"

Comment: Oh, I don't know how to write the program.

Comment: What does your course notes say about that ? 
have you asked questions to your teacher, teach-assistants, lab-assistants and other students ?

Comment: Why do you have this tagged as visual and basic if you are looking for C++ help?

Comment: My teacher is an a**hole. I missed a day of class a few weeks back and he acts like he can't help anybody now.

Comment: If you really want to be a developer then you will have to learn how to figure stuff out on your own eventually.  Now is a good time to learn.

Comment: Is there a book?  Did you go to the other classes after the one you've missed?

Comment: @Neal the OP didn't especially ask for code. Only "how to write the program" and that is completely different.

Comment: I'm not in school to be a programmer. I'm majoring in Electrical Engineering. My teachers accent is very hard to understand and his writing is like chicken scratch. I've only missed one day of class in the entire 2 months I've been in College. There's a book, but I can't afford it; so I'm using a guide from cplusplus.com

Comment: http://learning-computer-programming.blogspot.com/2007/06/learn-to-use-loops-in-c.html

Comment: @lilblaze I only hope for you he's not on Stack Overflow reading this right now.

Comment: He's practically blind behind a computer. He holds his face about 2 inches from the computer screen; I doubt he'll even be bothered to read this when he can barely read the few lines of text he says to input into the machine.

Comment: @lilblaze I know it is really amusing, but insulting your teacher instead of reading tutorials won't make your homework done.

Comment: The 3 answers I've received look like they have some substance to get me on the right track. Thank you everybody.

Comment: @lilblaze, if you are going to become an Electrical Engineer, you are going to have to learn a little bit about programming.  Sorry, but that's just how it is.  I suggest not eroding the failing relationship with your professor and getting a very good book on C or C++.  Your depth of knowledge can't be fixed overnight, but one of the "learn C in 24 hours books" might be all that you can handle right now.  Keep in mind those books typically have one hour "topics" which really take a day to understand.  Understand such a book isn't great, but perhaps you can complete it before your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do this:

- loop from 0 to 11 using a for loop (`for(size_t i = 0; i < 12; i++)`)
- for each i, std::cin into the item at index i `std::cin >> array[i];`

To print them out you can use a while loop with i--. It will stop when i is zero and it will be backwards.

Because this is a homework question, I won't give you the full code but I hope this answer helps.

Answer (score 2):

Learn about loops: `while` `for` `do, while` etcetera and you just might find the solution that you have been looking for

Example:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   cout << i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the quantity of numbers, you could insert them into the array in reverse order:

```
cin >> x[11]; cin >> x[10]; cin >> x[09]; //...
```

Next you would display the array in normal order:

```
cout << x[0]; cout << x[1]; cin << x[02]; //...
```

Since I didn't use a `for` loop, that's not going to help, is it?

The key concept is the 3rd parameter of the `for` loop, which can control the *direction* of a loop.

Let us investigate some examples:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2) {cout << i << endl; }
```

The above loop skips items because the variable is **incremented** by 2.  That is 2 is added to index variable.  This shows that loops don't always have to use ++.

So, what would happen if the index were set to the end value and then subtracted each time?

```
for (int i = 10; i >= 0; i -= 2) {cout << i << endl;}
```

This is for you to figure out.

Now, you will need to either ask questions in class, ask the professor after class or get a book that you will read and can understand easily (in addition to the one you have).